# Why do I get a "cannot find file" exception when my DB server is stopped?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm busy doing some analysis for exception handling, and when I stop my MS SQL server, and then execute this line:

```
var list = _expenseService.ListExpenseTypes().ToList();
```

in VS I get a "Provider failed to open" error dialogue, yet when I continue to get the Yellow Screen of Death, that shows

```
>
```

for the same line of code in the controller. How is this file exception being thrown when the original was "provider failed to open"?

Comment: Try to throw a new Exception("test") to verify if you get to see "test" or also "cannot find file".